# Sending Custom Message to Client in Tigase

Tags: xmpp, tigase

I am using Tigase server and smack library ( for android on client side ). In Tigase when user **A** send a message to user **B** and if user **B** is offline it store the message in database and send to user **B** later when it comes online again. I want to add one more functionality in this that when user **B** is offline server must tell user **A** that user **B** is offline and message will be delivered when he will come online.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, just use AMP: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0079.html‎ which is fully implemented on the Tigase server and should be activated by default. AMP gives you features to do precisely what you are asking for and much more. On the server side the AMP is implemented in such a way that it is very easy to extend. You just have to write/plug your own conditions, actions and other stuff.

Comment: Hefczys Can server send a message to user A on his own behalf. Because in **OfflineMessages** function savePacketForOffLineUser i detect that user B is offline.I am thinking that server should trigger a message to user A from there . Can i achieve in this way

Comment: @Hefczyc In Advanced Message Processing there is written **This protocol is typically used by clients to inform the receiving server how to deliver a particular stanza**. But my requirement is to send an additional message to client initiated from server. __will it work in my case as well__

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, AMP is exactly what you are looking for. Please have a look at the AMP spec. The server can send a message to user A when his message is either delivered or stored to offline storage, etc...